# Foreach loop, only show first element result in php?

Tags: php

I see some answers on this site but none apply for my particular problem.
When i trying to loop through array it shows only one array element. i have to get the loop results. i have tried many possible condition but nothing worked. please help me to resolve this. how to get the 1st and 2nd element result

output example

```
print_r($items[$i]['svg']);
```

foreach loop results showing only one result

```
Items array:


print_r($items);

  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => text
            [remove] => 1
            [rotate] => 0
            [text] => Hello
            [fontFamily] => Twine
            [color] => #000000
            [colors] => Array
                (
                    [0] => #000000
                )

            [stroke] => none
            [strokew] => 0
            [width] => 219px
            [height] => 109px
            [file] => 
            [confirmColor] => 
            [svg] => 
Hello

            [id] => 0
            [lockedProportion] => 1
            [align] => center
            [outlineC] => none
            [outlineW] => 0
            [top] => 22px
            [left] => 175px
            [zIndex] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => text
            [remove] => 1
            [rotate] => 0
            [text] => Tetst
            [fontFamily] => Twine
            [color] => #000000
            [colors] => Array
                (
                    [0] => #000000
                )

            [stroke] => none
            [strokew] => 0
            [width] => 207px
            [height] => 109px
            [file] => 
            [confirmColor] => 
            [svg] => 
Tetst

            [id] => 1
            [lockedProportion] => 1
            [align] => center
            [outlineC] => none
            [outlineW] => 0
            [top] => 195px
            [left] => 116px
            [zIndex] => 6
        )
```

when i try to print inside foreach it show only one result

```
$i = 0;

foreach($items as $item){
echo '<pre>';
    print_r($items[$i]); 
$i++
}
exit;
```

Comment: where is your `foreach` loop?

Comment: As far as I can see, it shows two results.

Comment: But when i print it shows only first result in the loop

Comment: where is `$items` array ? Because here we can see two different arrays

Comment: $i doesn't exists in your example you need this : `foreach($items as $i => $item){`

Comment: The result you are showing perfectly fits to your code (you got an array of arrays and you are printing the elements of the outer one). You should add the output you are expecting to your question.

Comment: @Parker  you need only `foreach($items as $item){echo '<pre>';print_r($item); }`

Comment: @MarcScheib Output example: print_r($items[$i]['svg']);

Comment: @Parker, please don't vote down any answer, we only try to help you...

Comment: Try this: `for ($i = 0; $i < count($items); $i++) {
    print($items[$i]['svg']);
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `foreach()` take care of numeric indexes itself, so no need of `$i` there.You have do this only:-

```
foreach($items as $item){
   echo '<pre/>';print_r($item); // print each sub-array of  original array
}
```

Output:- https://eval.in/851758

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
foreach($items as $i => $item){
    echo '<pre>';

    // either use this
    print_r($items[$i]); // it's actually not recomended

    // or use this
    print_r($item);

    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you write your array but I think use this

```
foreach($items as $item){
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($item); 
}
exit;
```

Comment: `$i` is unnecessary here. No use.Remove it. also missing `;` in `$i++`(which i added)

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating through `$items` while increment `$i` at the same time. It's not the same structure.
You are mingling `foreach()` and `for()`.

Do one or the others, but you have to choose :

```
$cnt = count($items);
for ($i = 0; $i < $cnt; ++$i) {
    print_r($items[$i]);
}
```

or

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    print_r($item);
}
```

Comment: Only  for the `or` solution. +1

Comment: @AlivetoDie Agreed, I honestly don't see the point of using the first piece of code, but the OP needs to see the difference to understand that viewpoint.